# sp_getapplock not working? I would expect the following code to make a table inaccessible for other sessions however this is not the case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

run the following in a sql server session

```
    CREATE DATABASE locktest
    GO

    CREATE TABLE locktest.dbo.lock_this_table (id INT)
    BEGIN TRAN
        EXEC locktest..sp_getapplock @Resource = 'lock_this_table',@LockMode = 'Exclusive'
```

In a separate window, execute the following code, I would expect it to hang whilst the first transaction remains open, any idea why it doesn't?

```
SELECT * FROM locktest.dbo.lock_this_table

INSERT INTO  locktest.dbo.lock_this_table
SELECT 4
```

Comment: You lock on a specific `lock_this_table` token (so other calls to sp_getapplock can work together in the same context) your not locking the table, is that what you want to do?

Comment: yes I want to make the table inaccessible to any other process

Comment: i can use this:  SELECT * FROM locktest.dbo.lock_this_table WITH (XLOCK, HOLDLOCK) to take the lock, although I am a little unsure about why sp_getapplock  isnt working as I expect

Comment: `sp_getapplock` is a mutex; its for signalling a "I am called `lock_this_table` and I'm locked" state without actually locking any database objects; other things can then ask `lock_this_table` if its locked and wait for it to become unlocked.

Comment: great thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

`sp_getapplock` doesn't lock tables. It is a non-SQL-Server-object locker. What does it lock, then? It locks the uniquely-named, non-case-sensitive string value called `@Resource`. This means that other users will only be blocked if they *also* use sp_getapplock`to attempt to acquire a lock on the identical string value of`@Resource` as was already locked by another connection.

To exclusively lock a table, you can just use this:

```
BEGIN TRAN;
SELECT TOP 0 * FROM locktest.dbo.lock_this_table WITH (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK);
-- Until the transaction is committed, this lock will be held
COMMIT TRAN;
```

Then if you do any operation to the table before the above transaction is committed, such as:

```
SELECT * FROM locktest.dbo.lock;
```

Then you will be blocked.